# Acessando dados de um array

Tags: php, array

Estou com um problema até meio "besta" aqui.

Eu tenho o seguinte array

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["produto"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["comprimento"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["largura"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["altura"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["diametro"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Mas toda vez que tento acessar algo dele, o php reclama `undefined index`

Estou acessando da seguinte forma

```
$vetor['produto']
$vetor['peso']
```

Qual seria a forma correta de acessá-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem o indice zero antes de id e dos demais, o certo é `$vetor[0]['produto']`. Uma forma de ver estrutura organizada do array ou objeto é usar esse código

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Assim fica explicito qual elemento contém qual.

A estrutura do seu é essa:

```
<?php 

$arr = array(
        0 => array('id' => 6, 'produto' => 7, 'peso' => 1, 'comprimento' => 16, 'largura' => 15, 'altura' => 5, 'diametro' => 0)
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

E sáida com o `<pre>` evidência quais elementos estão dentro do indice zero.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [produto] => 7
            [peso] => 1
            [comprimento] => 16
            [largura] => 15
            [altura] => 5
            [diametro] => 0
        )

)
```

Caso deseje eleminar o indice zero pode usar [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) ou [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

```
echo '<pre>';
$arr = array_shift($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Sáida:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 6
    [produto] => 7
    [peso] => 1
    [comprimento] => 16
    [largura] => 15
    [altura] => 5
    [diametro] => 0
)
```

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos, estava com o ideone até pronto aqui kkkk

Comment: @DiegoFelipe hahaha, até achei engraçado ver essa pergunta sem resposta por 40 minutos rs

Comment: Ia, mas antes tomei uma surra do ideone(mudei pra linguagem errada e achei que a soluçao estava errada tambem kkk), mas a resposta ia ser a mesma sua